# For loop in Javascript runs only once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here is my code. I do not quite understand why the for loop runs only once, both inner and outer. `nodeList.length` and `innerNodeList.length` show appropriate values when I generate alert messages. I see that both `i` and `j` do not increment beyond 0. Kindly point out anything wrong with the code.

```
function getCategoryElements() {
var newCategoryDiv = document.getElementById("category");
var nodeList = newCategoryDiv.childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
    var innerNodeList = nodeList[i].childNodes;
    alert("innerNodeList Length" + innerNodeList.length.toString());

    for (var j = 0; j < innerNodeList.length; ++j) {
        if (innerNodeList[j].nodeName == "SELECT") {
            alert("inside select Node value " + innerNodeList[j].nodeValue.toString());
            document.getElementById("newCategories").value = 
                document.getElementById("newCategories").value + '<%=delimiter%>' + innerNodeList[j].nodeValue;
        } else if (innerNodeList[j].nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {
            document.getElementById("newCategoriesData").value =
                document.getElementById("newCategoriesData").value + '<%=delimiter%>' + innerNodeList[j].nodeValue;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you build a fiddle ?

Comment: console.log the `nodeList.length` and `innerNodeList.length`. Im sure youll find that they are both equal to 1. Make a fiddle or post your HTML so we can see how the category div is set up.

Comment: Why are you putting var i outside loop statement? You can do:
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {....}

Comment: we'll also need more context - the error could be something as basic as the fact that your array only has 1 element.

Comment: @NickL. Really? That makes no difference. :)

Comment: Well, you use a line less. :D

Comment: @NickL. Read about Strict Mode, it will blow your mind. (BOOM)

Comment: Look at the console, I am guessing you got errors with the toString() with the nodeValue.

Comment: @epascarello thanks. That helps. I was getting some exceptions with toString. Later, I had to use <portlet:namespace /> to retrieve the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newCategoryDiv, nodeList, innerNodeList, innerNode, i, j;

newCategoryDiv = document.getElementById("category");
nodeList = newCategoryDiv.childNodes;

for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
    innerNodeList = nodeList[i].childNodes;
    alert("innerNodeList Length" + innerNodeList.length.toString());

    for (j = 0; j < innerNodeList.length; ++j) {
        innerNode = innerNodeList[j];
        if (innerNode.nodeName === "SELECT") {
            alert("inside select Node value " + innerNode.nodeValue.toString());
            document.getElementById("newCategories").value += '<%=delimiter%>' + innerNode.nodeValue;
        } else if (innerNode.nodeName === "TEXTAREA") {
            document.getElementById("newCategoriesData").value += '<%=delimiter%>' + innerNode.nodeValue;
        }
        // Will this work?
        alert('Does this alert appear'); 
    }
}
```

I took the liberty to refactor your code and clean it up a little bit.  In case you're not aware, all variables have function scope in Javascript, so no matter where you declare them within a single function, Javascript treats them as if the variable declaration is the first statement.

It appears that your code is syntactically correct, and so I think that the most logical place to look for a problem is that there could be an error occurring after the last `alert` function call.

In order to check this, try adding another `alert` function call to the end of the inner loop.  If it doesn't run, you'll know this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. The last alert was not appearing. I looked at console under developer tools, there were perhaps 2 errors. toString was throwing up error as @epascarello pointed out. Also, '<%=delimiter%>' was throwing an error. When both corrected, the error was that node.value was null. Hence, I used <portlet:namespace /> to retrieve both elements.